# RISC V gcc toolchain leaking stack when using mret

Tags: c, gcc, riscv

I am using the official [riscv-gnu-toolchain](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain/) to compile my custom kernel written in C. I have the following function to return control from kernel mode to user mode (most parts are removed for clarity):

```c
void scheduler_switch_to(int proc_index) 
{
    ProcessControlBlock *pcb = processes + proc_index;

    CSR_WRITE(CSR_MEPC, pcb->pc);
    // other csr writes and register restoration removed
    __asm__(
        "mret\n\t"
    );
    __builtin_unreachable();
}
```

When I compile this code, using no optimization with the riscv gnu toolchain, I get the following assembly code:

```
000104b8 <scheduler_switch_to> (File Offset: 0x4b8):
scheduler_switch_to():
   104b8:   fd010113            addi    sp,sp,-48
   104bc:   02812623            sw  s0,44(sp)
   104c0:   03010413            addi    s0,sp,48
   104c4:   fca42e23            sw  a0,-36(s0)
   104c8:   fdc42703            lw  a4,-36(s0)
   104cc:   09c00793            li  a5,156
   104d0:   02f70733            mul a4,a4,a5
   104d4:   000117b7            lui a5,0x11
   104d8:   7f078793            addi    a5,a5,2032 # 117f0 <processes> (File Offset: 0x17f0)
   104dc:   00f707b3            add a5,a4,a5
   104e0:   fef42623            sw  a5,-20(s0)
   104e4:   fec42783            lw  a5,-20(s0)
   104e8:   0047a783            lw  a5,4(a5)
   104ec:   34179073            csrw    mepc,a5
   104f0:   30200073            mret
```

This code is obviously missing the register save/load routine, but notice stack allocation at `104b8`, which is never released, as gcc does not understand the returning nature of the `mret` instruction.

I looked into a couple possible solutions, but I could not find any gcc hint to release the allocated stack. The only workaround I could imagine is resetting the stack-pointer to the stack-top every time the kernel is called from an interrupt, but this would be hacky, and might make further extension much more difficult... When I turn on optimization, gcc optimizes ou stack allocation, but this is just a bandaid fix, since it still does not understand that `mret` is a return-like keyword.

Is there a normal way to tell gcc, that the method will switch execution context and to release the allocated stack?

Answer (score 2):

It will not. The compiler knows that function return (including the epilogue) will never be reached, so there is no point to generate that code.

You need to tell the compiler to do not to allocate the stack for this function

```
void __attribute__((noreturn, naked)) scheduler_switch_to(int proc_index)
```

I would personally split this function into two. One naked which does actual context switch and "normal" C function for pcb`s manipulations.

Comment: This just propagates the problem one level up the callstack. The function calling the context switching function will still only release the stack after the `jal` subroutine call.

Comment: I think I understand now. The `mret` instruction "completes" the stack, meaning it can be discarded. So when the next interrupt happens, the stack pointer can be reset to the stack top without loosing any data... Thanks!